# Calculating days, hours, minutes, seconds between 2 dates including reversal calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have to calculate days, hours, minutes, seconds between 2 dates which is OK, but if the second date is in the past the function below doesnt work:

```
var date = '2017-12-07';
    $('#count').countdown(date, function(event) {

        $(this).html(event.strftime('' + 
            '<div class="count-block days">%D<span class="count-label">day%!d</span></div>' + 
            '<div class="count-block hours">%H<span class="count-label">%!H:hour,hours;</span></div>' + 
            '<div class="count-block minutes">%M<span class="count-label">%!M:minute,minutes;</span></div>' + 
            '<div class="count-block seconds">%S<span class="count-label">%!S:second,seconds;</span></div>'
        ));
    });
```

with date '2017-12-07' it works
My question is, is it possible to make this function works for dates in the past?
with date '2015-12-07' it doesnt works
Thank you in advance

Comment: well what is this random library you are using? Does the library support it?

Comment: look at momentjs library

Comment: This is using jquery.countdown.js plugin and no such option as far as I read.. I checked moment.js library also doesnt provide this extra to calculate from date in the past

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a sufficient explanation, particularly when the relevant code is not provided.

Comment: Note that date calculations aren't necessarily symmetric, 31 Jan plus one month might be 28 Feb, but 28 Feb minus one month is probably 28 Jan, but business rules might have something to say about that. Or not.